# Calling method of extended jquery widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I have a jquery widget like this:

```
$.widget("ui.MyWidget", {
              options: {            
            Value1: 10,
            Value1: 20,
        },
// and other methods like _create,...
});
```

And, i am extending it like this:

```
$.widget("ui.MyExtWidget", $.extend({
            options: {
            Value3: 20,
        }}, $.ui.MyWidget.prototype, {
        myNewMethod: function(){
            alert(this.options.Value1+this.options.Value3);
        }
}
```

I have to call the "myNewMethod" in my html.

My html code is like this:

```
$("#Div1").MyExtWidget();
$("#Div1").MyExtWidget("myNewMethod");
```

I am getting exception like this while using the above code **cannot call methods on TimeSpanHeader prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'myNewMethod'**

What is the way to call the "myNewMethod" method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget factory provides a way to extend from an existing widget with `$.widget` constructor:

```
$.widget("ui.MyExtWidget", $.ui.MyWidget, {
    options: {
        alertText: ''
    },
    myNewMethod: function() {
        alert('Value1 = ' + this.options.Value1);
        alert('alertText = ' + this.options.alertText);
    }
});
```

**Note:** The constructor will take care of extending the options as well. This is the method used in the jQuery UI library itself. For instance, the widget `ui.mouse` has options and a lot of the other widgets inherits from it and have their own extra options along with the ones from ui.mouse.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/3ZTne/)**

---

From the Widget Factory [wiki post](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory):

> The widget factory is a simple function on the global jQuery object -
>   jQuery.widget - that accepts 2 or 3 arguments.
>
> jQuery.widget("namespace.widgetname", **/* optional - an existing widget prototype to inherit from */***, / An object literal to become the widget's prototype*/ {...} );
>
> **The second (optional) argument is a widget prototype to inherit from**.
>   For instance, jQuery UI has a "mouse" plugin on which the rest of the
>   interaction plugins are based. In order to achieve this, draggable,
>   droppable, etc. all inherit from the mouse plugin like so:
>   jQuery.widget( "ui.draggable", $.ui.mouse, {...} ); If you do not
>   supply this argument, the widget will inherit directly from the "base
>   widget," jQuery.Widget (note the difference between lowercase "w"
>   jQuery.widget and uppercase "W" jQuery.Widget).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, In this case, we can't add a new option to base widget's options only know.

Comment: Of course you can, i've updated the anwser and the fiddle to show you. This is the exact method used by the widgets in the jQuery UI library.